# Bot Framework Emulator - How to force the emulator to use a specific port

Tags: botframework, botframeworkemulator

Each time I run the Bot Framework Emulator it spins it up with a new port number.

[image]

How do I force the emulator to always use a specific port each time the app is opened?

Reason: We are connecting from a UI to the emulator using a URL which is working perfectly (in the case above, http://localhost:55583) but we can't have to keep changing the source code of our UI to the new port number each time we open the emulator.

Please help, this has been driving me insane.

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to connect to the emulator port, rather than the port the messaging API (3978) is running on?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/49f2346f223ae4ffced68ad383602bb455a7496d/packages/app/main/src/server/restServer.ts#L152-L162) , on startup a [port CAN BE is supplied](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/36b01c026050092bec2dd3a3da7b79646cd4354e/packages/app/main/src/emulator.ts#L83-L90), but [they don't](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/36b01c026050092bec2dd3a3da7b79646cd4354e/packages/app/main/src/commands/emulatorCommands.ts#L172).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently (as @matt-stannett pointed out).

You can clone the repo, make changes and build your own.

Additionally; please file a enhancement/DCR in the emulator repo if so desired.

Comment: Okay no worries happy to make the changes myself for now. How do I go about building the application though?

Comment: Here are the instructions: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-build-from-source

Comment: Perfect, I could not find this anywhere!